# Encerrar palabras entre asteriscos y hacerla strong

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Artículo" class="articulo"></textarea>

<p class="articuloPreview"></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>    
    $(".articulo").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(".articuloPreview").text(value);
    }).keyup();
</script>
```

La  función que cumple este código es mostrar en 'tiempo real' lo que escribes en el textarea.
Lo que necesito es que si encierran una palabra o una oración entre asteriscos (*) este texto se vuelva **negrita**. Agradezco sus respuestas.

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero no me funciona:

```
$(".articuloPreview").text(value.replace('*', '<strong>value</strong>'));
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? La pregunta es interesante, pero carece de código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora. Así sería hacer todo por ti, y no es la idea del sitio. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Buena bservación, ya corrigo ese error, mis disculpas.

Comment: Quizás buscas esto: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi solución esta basada en reemplazar el texto  pero utilizando una expresión regular (aún puedes mejorar la que yo te dejo de muestra para optimizar lo que necesites).

Te dejo esta web para que puedas hacer pruebas y armar una buena expresión regular. https://regex101.com/

Dentro de la expresión lo que sugiero es capturar el grupo de tu palabra o frase y luego reemplazar y insertar ese grupo capturado con `$1` (o el numero del grupo que necesites segun la expresión que se utilice) encerrado en la etiqueta `<strong></strong>` para obtener el resultado que necesitas `<strong>TU PALABRA O FRASE</strong>`, en este caso la ventaja es que el replace soporta expresiones regulares sin problemas y en este caso se puede aprovechar muy bien.

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que sería mi solución.

```html
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Artículo" class="articulo"></textarea>

<p class="articuloPreview"></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(".articulo").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex = /\*([a-zA-Z\d\w\s]+)\*/gi
    $(".articuloPreview").html(value.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>"));
  }).keyup();
</script>
```

--- EDIT ---
Quiero aclarar también cambie el metodo `.text` a `.html` para que puedas reemplazar tu texto con las etiquetas y no se escriba directamente `<strong>tu texto</strong>`

Espero te sea útil!

Comment: Gracias por agregar tu respuesta me parece más que excelente y muy bien explicada, +1

Answer (score 3):

No considero que necesariamente usar [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) sea el mejor camino puesto que no queremos reemplazar la cadena de texto actual sino simplemente si se cumple algo entonces modificar su aspecto

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

- Captura el evento `keyup` del input donde el usuario escribe
- Captura en una variable la etiqueta HTML donde se mostrará el texto que el usuario escriba
- Asignamos al párrafo el texto que escribe el usuario
- Posterior mediante un `if` evaluamos:

  - Si el valor introducido al inicio y al final de una cadena es un asterico
  - En caso afirmativo, asignamos una clase al párrafo que contiene el texto con la cual daremos un estilo de `bold` a la fuente
  - En caso de que no se encuentren los dos asteriscos entonces removemos dicha clase

Código:

```html
    <style>
      .modificada {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
    <input id="texto" type="text" />
    <p id="muestra">
      
    </p>
    <script>
      let texto = document.getElementById('texto');
      let muestra = document.getElementById('muestra');
      
      texto.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        muestra.innerText = texto.value;
        if (texto.value.charAt() === '*' && texto.value.charAt(texto.value.length-1) === '*') {
          muestra.classList.add('modificada');
        } else {
          muestra.classList.remove('modificada');
        }
      });
    </script>
```

**Fuentes**

- [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charAt)
- [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: No le funcionaría si tienes caracteres adicionales y me parece que lo que desea es que todas las palabras comanzadas y terminadas con * sean negritas, yo le recomendaria aplicar una regex. o simplemente buscar todas las coincidencias de *¨y ver si cumple la regla que desea.

Comment: Vale, probaré crear una respuesta utilizando regex.

Answer (score 3):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que un elemento [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/textarea) sólo permite texto sin formato. Por lo tanto, usar un `textarea` para esta tarea es misión imposible.

**APROXIMACIÓN A UNA SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible aproximación es usar un elemento con [contenido editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content), como por ejemplo un `div` con el atributo `contenteditable="true"`.

Luego, podríamos usar una [expresión regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) para capturar las palabras delimitadas por '*' y reemplazar cada asterisco con un elemento `<strong>` y `</strong>` respectivamente.

Una expresión regular podría ser:

```
let regexp = /\*(.*?)\*/
```

Ahora, la idea es que cada elemento encontrado que coincida con la expresión regular debe ser reemplazado de tal manera que los asteriscos inicial y final se sustituyan por los valores adecuados.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let regexp = /\*(.*?)\*/g;
let test = '*Hola* mundo de la *programación*.';

console.log(test);

const replacer = str => {
  let value = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
  return '<strong>'.concat(value).concat('</strong>');
}

console.log(test.replace(regexp, replacer));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Teniendo esto, ya podríamos ver una implementación de lo que tratamos de lograr, pero nos ayudaremos de un botón para realizar la acción:

```js
const regexp = /\*(.*?)\*/g;

const replacer = str => {
  let value = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
  return '<strong>'.concat(value).concat('</strong>');
}

const onClick = event => {
  let value = document.getElementById('editable').innerText;
  let replace = value.replace(regexp, replacer);
  document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML = replace;
}

document.getElementById('replace').addEventListener('click', onClick);
document.getElementById('clean').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML = '';
});
```

```css
#editable {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h3>Escriba algo:</h3>
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
<br>
<button id="replace">Reemplazar</button>
<button id="clean">Limpiar</button>
```